# Inverter valores da pilha

Tags: c, stack

Estou tentando inverter a ordem dos elementos da pilha usando o laço `while`, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
pilha* inverte(pilha **p) {
    pilha *outra = cria(); //aloca e seta a qnt com 0
    while(vazia(&p)) {
         outra->dados[outra->qnt++] = (*p)->dados[(*p)->qnt];
        (*p)->qnt--;
    }
    return outra;
}
```

Estou tentando pegar posição atual.

Comment: O código está bem esquisito, mas só com isto não sei se dá para responder adequadamente. Precisa colocar algo mais para entender como chegou aí e se o problema não está outro lugar.

Comment: A pilha é só de valores.

Comment: Esta exibindo um valor a mais. http://ideone.com/Q1QL37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu dei uma melhorada em várias coisas, entre elas simplifiquei a passagem de parâmetro, não precisa passar ponteiro de ponteiro. Mas o erro principal é que o operador `>=` não podia ser usado no `while`. Quando chega a 0 tem que parar, por causa do `=` ele fazia uma operação a mais. Mas também há um problema do outro lado. Começa pegando o índice equivalente à quantidade de elementos na pilha. Como índice começa em 0, o último é a quantidade menos 1. Com essas duas alterações funciona. Mas ainda não está liberando a memória (eu sei que é algo desnecessário nesse exemplo, mas é bom se acostumar fazer certo sempre):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

typedef struct pilha {
    int qnt;
    int dados[MAX];
} Pilha;
Pilha* cria() {
    Pilha *p = malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    if (p != NULL) p->qnt = 0;
    return p;
}
void insere(Pilha *p, int valor) {
    p->dados[p->qnt] = valor;
    p->qnt++;
}
void exibe(Pilha *p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p->qnt; i++) printf("%3d", p->dados[i]);
}
Pilha* inverte(Pilha *p) {
    Pilha *outra = cria();
    while (p->qnt > 0) {
        outra->dados[outra->qnt] = p->dados[p->qnt - 1];
        p->qnt--;
        outra->qnt++;
    }
    return outra;
}
int main() {
    Pilha *p = cria();
    insere(p, 32);
    insere(p, 45);
    insere(p, 78);
    exibe(p);
    p = inverte(p);
    printf("\n");
    exibe(p);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/17g67X). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zeqydndl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/InvertStack.c).